# UWP InkToolbar can't be actived on app loaded

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

My UWP App has two inkToolbars. As is shown in the picture, the horizontal one is customized totally. It has some inkToolbarCustomToolButtons like "NewInk", "SaveInk","Settngs"， and so on.

The Vertical is half customized. It has some original inkToolbarToolButtons, and some customized buttons.

[image]

Now if I only use the vertical inkToolbar, the fisrt inkToolbarBallpointPenButton is active, and I can draw on my app loaded.

```
<InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar1" x:FieldModifier="Public" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan ="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" InitialControls="None" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonNewInk" Click="toggleButtonNewInk_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Page2">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipNewInk" Content="NewInk"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonClearAllInk" Click="toggleButtonClearAllInk_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Document">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipClearAllInk" Content="ClearAllInk"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonLoadInk" Click="toggleButtonLoadInk_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="OpenFile">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipLoadInk" Content="LoadInk"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonSaveInk" Click="toggleButtonSaveInk_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Save">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipSaveInk" Content="SaveInk"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonSavePictures" Click="toggleButtonSavePictures_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Pictures">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipSavePictures" Content="SavePictures"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonBackground" Click="toggleButtonBackground_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="BrowsePhotos">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipBackground" Content="SelectBackground"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonBackgroundOpacity" Click="toggleButtonBackgroundOpacity_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="HideBcc">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipBackgroundOpacity" Content="BackgroundOpacity"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonCopy" Click="toggleButton_Copy">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Copy}">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipCopy" Content="Copy"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonCut" Click="toggleButton_Cut">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Cut}">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipCut" Content="Cut"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonPaste" Click="toggleButton_Paste">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Paste}">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipPaste" Content="Paste"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="undoButton" Click="Undo_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Undo">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipUndo" Content="Undo"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="redoButton" Click="Redo_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Redo">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipRedo" Content="Redo"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonReplay" Click="toggleButtonReplay_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Slideshow">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipReplay" Content="Replay"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonReset" Click="toggleButtonReset_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Rotate">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipStopReplay" Content="StopReplay"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonSettings" Click="toggleButtonSettings_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Uid="ToolTipSettings" Content="Settings"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </SymbolIcon>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
        </InkToolbar>

        <InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar2" x:FieldModifier="Public" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <InkToolbar.Resources>
                <BrushCollection x:Key="CalligraphicPenPalette">
                    <SolidColorBrush>Black</SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush>White</SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD1D3D4"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA7A9AC"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF808285"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF58595B"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB31564"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFF5500"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFAA00"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFCE00"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFE600"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA2E61B"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF26E600"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF008055"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF00AACC"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF004DE6"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3D00B8"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF6600CC"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF600080"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF7D7C4"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFBB9167"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8E562E"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF613D30"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFF80FF"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFC680"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF80"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF80FF9E"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF80D6FF"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFBCB3FF"/>
                </BrushCollection>
                <local:CalligraphicPen x:Key="CalligraphicPen"/>
            </InkToolbar.Resources>
            <InkToolbarCustomPenButton x:Name="calligraphyPen"
                CustomPen="{StaticResource CalligraphicPen}"
                Palette="{StaticResource CalligraphicPenPalette}"
                SelectedBrushIndex="0"
                MinStrokeWidth="4"
                MaxStrokeWidth="10"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="CalligraphyPen">
                <InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
                    <InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl/>
                </InkToolbarCustomPenButton.ConfigurationContent>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xEDFB;" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xF0C7;" 
                                                   Foreground="{x:Bind calligraphyPen.SelectedBrush, Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </InkToolbarCustomPenButton>

            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toolButtonColorPicker" Click="ToolButton_ColorPicker" ToolTipService.ToolTip="ColorPicker">
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Palette.png"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toolButtonLasso" Click="ToolButton_Lasso" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Selection tool">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind LassoSelect}"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToggleButton x:Name="toggleTouch" Click="Toggle_Touch" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Touch Writing">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind TouchWriting}"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToggleButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToggleButton x:Name="toggleMouse" Click="Toggle_Mouse" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Mouse Writing">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="backgroundGrid" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Path Data="M9.9999777,8.0546999L9.9999777,15.988959 7.9999777,15.988959 7.9999777,8.0547061 7.9353534,8.063777C4.5788473,8.5782027,1.9999997,11.485739,1.9999995,14.982962L1.9999995,15.988976 15.99999,15.988976 15.99999,17.988976 1.9999995,17.988976 1.9999995,22.999972C1.9999997,26.858977 5.1399997,29.999981 8.9999996,29.999981 12.859999,29.999981 16,26.858977 16,22.999972L16,14.982962C16,11.485739,13.421152,8.5782027,10.064646,8.063777z M8.9999996,7.982954L8.996245,7.9830017 9.0037543,7.9830017z M17.968911,0C17.970911,0.24400043 17.95291,2.4140015 16.674872,3.5620012 16.082855,4.0940018 15.322832,4.3240013 14.466807,4.2230015 13.449776,4.1050014 12.680753,3.6420012 12.061735,3.2710018 11.263712,2.7910013 10.8857,2.5880013 10.280682,2.828001 9.5819117,3.1010017 9.605373,4.7114782 9.805019,5.9119158L9.8240258,6.021059 9.9187862,6.0295C14.450976,6.4911938,18,10.330144,18,14.982962L18,22.999972C18,27.961978 13.962,31.999984 8.9999996,31.999984 4.0379997,31.999984 -2.3841858E-07,27.961978 0,22.999972L0,14.982962C-2.3841858E-07,10.485238,3.316365,6.7480278,7.6313664,6.086832L7.8013331,6.0629797 7.7834183,5.9472485C7.5516907,4.3561869 7.5199753,1.7596569 9.5526606,0.9640007 11.098707,0.36000061 12.20374,1.0230007 13.091766,1.5560007 13.615781,1.8710012 14.109796,2.1680012 14.698814,2.2370014 15.058824,2.2770014 15.228829,2.1730013 15.336833,2.0760012 15.817847,1.6470013 15.970852,0.50200081 15.968852,0.015000343z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFDFD" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </InkToolbarCustomToggleButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonZoomIn" Click="toggleButtonZoomIn_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="ZoomIn" ToolTipService.ToolTip="ZoomIn"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonZoomOut" Click="toggleButtonZoomOut_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="ZoomOut" ToolTipService.ToolTip="ZoomOut"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton x:Name="toggleButtonFullExtent" Click="toggleButtonFullExtent_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Zoom" ToolTipService.ToolTip="FullExtent"/>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
        </InkToolbar>
```

[image]

But!!! When I loaded the two inkToolbars, inkToolbarBallpointPenButton is inactive for some unknown reason. I have to click other buttons first, and then click inkToolbarBallpointPenButton, it became active only in this way.

Do anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: Please add some XAML and code-behind (if used), so we can understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!!!
In inkToolbar1, I set I TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}".

Delete TargetInkCanvas!!!